# solving assignment error in typescript: «Module parse failed»

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to assign a object to `initialState` variable, the `selectedActivity` type is `Activity | undefined` and after Nullish Coalescing operator (??) the `emptyActivity` is of type `Activity`.
but when this line execute, it throws an error that says: *Module parse failed: Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.*
Code:

```
interface Props {
    selectedActivity: Activity | undefined
    closeForm: () => void
}
export default function ActivityForm({ selectedActivity, closeForm }: Props) {
    const emptyActivity: Activity = {
        id: '',
        title: '',
        date: '',
        description: '',
        category: '',
        city: '',
        venue: '',
    }
const initialState = selectedActivity ?? emptyActivity;
```

and this is Activity interface:

```
export interface Activity {
    id: string
    title: string
    date: string
    description: string
    category: string
    city: string
    venue: string
}
```

I'm coding a react project and I want to solve the assignment error.

Answer (score 1):

As the error said that your loader can't handle this syntax, maybe it is old, and you need to update it, but as a temporary solution you can convert this syntax to `ternary operator` syntax and it should work.

```
const initialState = selectedActivity ? selectedActivity : emptyActivity;
```